# Convert bytes or str to str in Python 2 and 3 using the same code

Tags: python

I have code that uses `subprocess.check_output()` which returns a `str` in Python 2, and `bytes` in Python 3. Is there any way to have code that works in Python 2 and 3 and converts it to a `str`?

I.e. I want this, but more elegantly:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(...)
if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
   output = output.decode()
```

To be clear, I don't want `unicode` in Python 2, I want it to leave it as a `str`.

Comment: Does not work in Python 2 - `TypeError: str() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`

Comment: oh oops. i misread

Comment: Thanks for being more explicit. In future, when you state that "it doesn't work", you really must state what happened instead, and what should have happened.  This helps uncover any gaps and misunderstandings as to what you are trying to achieve. I could have given you the `universal_newlines=True` option much earlier had you provided this info up front.

Comment: To be fair the *title of the question* says "Convert bytes or str to str", *and* I said "... and converts it to `str`?". I think I was explicit enough.

Comment: It is commonly misunderstood that `str` in Python 2 is not the same thing as `str` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can sidestep the issue with `universal_newlines=True` in calls to `subprocess` functions.

```
subprocess.check_output(..., universal_newlines=True)
```

If you check the output types:

```
$ python2 -c "import subprocess;print(type(subprocess.check_output('ls')))"
<type 'str'>

$ python2 -c "import subprocess;print(type(subprocess.check_output('ls', \
                                           universal_newlines=True)))"
<type 'str'>

$ python3 -c "import subprocess;print(type(subprocess.check_output('ls')))"
<class 'bytes'>

$ python3 -c "import subprocess;print(type(subprocess.check_output('ls', \
                                           universal_newlines=True)))"
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the general question, but it is definitely a good solution in my particular case!

Comment: So this produces a bytestring in Python 2, a Unicode text string in Python 3.

Comment: Yes, which is what I want - a `str` in both cases.